# Python/Kivy: access property on widget initialization

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

How can I use a custom set `StringProperty` in Kivy language, before its base widget's initalization?
The problem in the following snippet is that when the `MyInput` class is initialized, the property `key` isn't set yet and the instructions after it will raise a KeyError Exception.

Is it possible at all to design such a subclass, or there's a better approach?

```
MainWidget:
    details: some_dictionary[]
    MyInput:
        key: 'firstkey'
    MyInput:
        key: 'secondkey'


<MyInput@TextInput>:
    key: ''
    text: self.parent.details[self.key]
```

Both points should be clear without saying, but:
 - I've been working with Kivy for 3 days,
 - there's a whole lot of other properties depending on the `key` property, which were removed for a better explaination of my question.

Kivy 1.9.1 - Python 3.4.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use default values to overcome your issue. Here is a working example

```
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):


        Builder.load_string("""\
<MyBox>:
    details: {'firstkey': 'pop', 'secondkey': 'corn'}
    MyInput:
        key: 'firstkey'
    MyInput:
        key: 'secondkey'


<MyInput@TextInput>:
    key: ''
    text: self.parent.details.get(self.key, '')
""")
        return MyBox()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: interesting approach. in the past hour I've been working on a different way to solve this, basically using the `on_key` property to update the text accordingly.

Comment: it turns out that your suggestion doesn't actually solve the problem, as it unbinds the property and requires extra watchers to be set up in order to propagate changes in the value.